# Hide scrollbar when not necessary, but keep the screen width consistent

Tags: css, browser

On pretty much any web browsers, the scroll bar is displayed only when it is needed. This is fine, but the problem is that when the scroll bar is displayed, the width of the screen shrinks. This results in an awkward shift of the content on the screen.

I want to prevent this behaviour so that the width of the screen is consistent whether the scroll bar is displayed or not displayed. How can I achieve this? I don't want to use JavaScript/jQuery if possible.

Comment: How do you define 'screen' for this purpose?

Comment: I meant 'screen' by the browser window size that is visible to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try jQuery "perfect scroll" plugin here is: http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/

Answer (score 0):

Set the vertical scroll bar on the page like this with css,

```
html
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

this will place the scroll bar in the window and it will stop the screen from jumping when it is needed.

cheers

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. It displays a scroll bar all the time. I don't want to display a scroll bar if it is not necessary, i.e. the whole content fits in the current window size.

Comment: I think this is the only way by using css that wouldn't make your window shift those couple of pixels.